# only that ... or only that's ....?

Tags: grammar, errors

I have never seen the following expression : only that’s ….. ( I understand “only that” grammatically instead of “only that’s “….. )

> ‘Have you seen her yet?’  he asked.
>
> ‘Not yet.’
>
> ‘But you’ve heard something about her?’
>
> ‘Only that’s she’s an expert in her line.’
>
> [Source: From Dashiell Hammett, *Red Harvest*]

I wonder if this is grammatically correct (common usage) or a kind of dialect used among English-speaking people.

I have searched the similar expression on the Internet. And I found some. 
So it doesn’t seem to be less frequently used. I would appreciate it if you could give me a piece advice on this. (This is way over my head.)

Answer (score 1):

A Google books search for the phrase "she's an expert in her line" turns up five matches for Dashiell Hamemett's *Red Harvest*, ranging across the years of publication [1965](https://books.google.com/books?id=BpErAAAAYAAJ&q=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&dq=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMIsbW2ldzmxwIVhCmICh3ACQ8G), [1972](https://books.google.com/books?id=3ONLGBlaDRYC&pg=PA461&dq=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIsbW2ldzmxwIVhCmICh3ACQ8G#v=onepage&q=%22she%E2%80%99s%20an%20expert%20in%20her%20line%22&f=false), [1982](https://books.google.com/books?id=U_Gh4OJqQXMC&q=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&dq=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBGoVChMIsbW2ldzmxwIVhCmICh3ACQ8G), [1999](https://books.google.com/books?id=FV2vAAAAIAAJ&q=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&dq=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIsbW2ldzmxwIVhCmICh3ACQ8G), and [2010](https://books.google.com/books?id=P93cAJeOD0EC&pg=PA27&dq=%22she%E2%80%99s+an+expert+in+her+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIsbW2ldzmxwIVhCmICh3ACQ8G#v=onepage&q=%22she%E2%80%99s%20an%20expert%20in%20her%20line%22&f=false). In every case, the line of dialogue is given as

> "Only that she's an expert in her line."

A search for the phrase "Only that's she's an expert," on the other hand, yields no matches.

Although the evidence would be even more convincing if Google Books offered a match to a version of the book from closer to 1929, when *Red Harvest* was first published, I consider it highly likely that the contraction *that's* in the wording "Only that's she's an expert in her line" is simply a typo for *that* in the edition that you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

I may have watched too many loony toons with the rooster "[Foghorn Leghorn](https://www.google.com/search?q=Road+Island+Red&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI_tPrlM3mxwIVyHY-Ch0BOA3y&biw=1080&bih=1775#tbm=isch&q=foghorn+leghorn)" as a kid but this is how that decodes in my head:

> ‘Only, that is, she is an expert in her line.’

So it, I say, it is simply missing a few commas, that is.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard/seen that used before. I've lived in the Northeast U.S., the Southeast, and in Texas, and then the Southeast again. So I've heard a "right many" dialects. :)

I think it's just a typo.

Considering: "Only that’s she’s an expert in her line."
Literally means: "Only that is she is an expert in her line."

(and that doesn't make any sense... in any dialect)